# dataframe apply lambda function that requires value from row n+1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and geopy to calculate distances between two geo coordinates as follows :

```
import geopy.distance

distCalcExample = geopy.distance.geodesic((49.18443, -0.36098), (49.184335, -0.361185)).m

r = {'poly':[(49.419453, 0.232884),(49.41956, 0.23269),(49.41956, 0.23261),(49.41953, 0.23255),(49.41946, 0.23247)]}
df=pd.DataFrame(r)
df['dist']=0
df
```

[image]

I need to calculate the distance between coordinates of rows n and n+1.
I was thinking of using geopy as in distCalcExample, along with apply and a lambda function.
But i have not managed to achieve it. What would be the simplest way to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a column including the shifted values

```
df["shifted"] = df["poly"].shift()
```

Then use apply rowwise:

```
df[["poly","shifted"]].apply(lambda x: geopy.distance.geodesic(x[0],x[1]).m,axis=1)
```

Comment: Because there will be nan in the fist row this will fail. I would suggest adding a condition in the apply function: `df[["poly","shifted"]].apply(lambda x: geopy.distance.geodesic(x[0],x[1]).m if not np.all(np.isnan(x[1])) else np.nan,axis=1)`

Comment: I think for Nan-objects it treats them as (0,0) coordinates - so depending on the aim this may or may not give a proper answer for the first element. In any case, no exception is thrown

Comment: I have tried it and gave an error this is the only reason I suggested the condition in the apply function